# Connecting to SQL Server with Python's Pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a database using python's PYODBC package but running into an error. I believe my issue is I can only run SSMS as administrator in order to access server and login. Here is my python code below. Any ideas?

```
    import pyodbc

    conn = pyodbc.connect('driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                          'Server = <my server here>;'
                          'Database = <my database here>;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

My error:

> login failed for user

Comment: FYI: `'` is quite different to `\`` - and its the second you need to mark a code block.

Comment: did you set the correct port?

Comment: I didn't set a port at all

Comment: _I can only run SSMS as administrator in order to access server and login._ To confirm: So you only have Windows authentication enabled on the SQL Server instance and only members of the Administrators group are permitted to login?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Correct

Comment: The user you are running this Python code under needs to be added to SQL Server as a Windows Login, with correct permissions to your database

Comment: @Charlieface I am the user and the administrator

Comment: You might still need to add it as a Login, as Windows prevents admin users from taking full admin rights by default